# How to count Collective failure rate for chips?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

i wonder where 0,81 from, from this lecture www.eng.auburn.edu/~agrawvd/COURSE/FULL/lec3.ppt -page 14.
i try find specific area in failure rate, but it seems i can't find 0,81 from
let's say Chips = C , then there's Cn chips that has failure rate, 
so the formula would be C1+C2+...Cn - [?] = answer
could anyone understand about this test economic.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

The collective failure rate is one or both may happen =
A + (1 - A) x B = A + B - A x B

The 0.81 is from A x B (=0.9x0.9).

I don't use statistics often, but for 3 elements, doing the above recursively, the combined rate =
A + B + C - AxB - AxC - BxC + AxBxC